# Route isn't valid (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

The route for my `Login.vue` component works ([see here](http://fabricepallaud.com/timelog/#/Login)) whereas the route for my `SignUp.vue` component doesn't ([see here](http://fabricepallaud.com/timelog/#/SignUp)). Why?

[Full source code here](https://github.com/fabricepallaud/timelog/tree/dev)

Router config file (src/router/index.js):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Home from '../components/Home.vue';
import SignUp from '../components/SignUp.vue';
import Login from '../components/Login.vue';

import Router from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: 'signup',
    component: SignUp
  },
  ]
});
```

Root HTML file (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>timelog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <router-link to="/"><h1>Timelog</h1></router-link>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `path: 'signup',` to `path: '/signup',`

Comment: Thanks, I want to die though. I spent like an hour on this without spotting that missing slash